# NameError: name '_' is not defined in django

Tags: python, django

```
class Food(models.Model):
```

Error:

```
File "D:\Django\restaurant\foods\models.py", line 7, in Food
description = models.CharField(_("توضیحات"), max_length=50)
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome in stackoverflow. Please provide more details, especially code broader code example and proper error traceback.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to register **`_`**:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Food(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("توضیحات"), max_length=50)
    ...
```

Also use in **models.py** `gettext_lazy` - [**Lazy translation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the import wrong

it should be:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

instead of

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext
```